# How to get the URL from Vimeo , so that I can fetch JSON

Tags: android, json, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, vimeo-android

I have been roaming around https://developer.vimeo.com for quite a time - but I am not getting the API URL to fetch the `JSON` - so that I can parse it and play Vimeo video on my android app by parsing the data returned as JSON response.

I am not getting the right URL to fetch `JSON`, after that, I can parse data easily.

Any help how to get the URL from Vimeo to parse the JSON data(I have also created an app and got the unique`CLIENT IDENTIFIER AND SECRETS`.But I am not being able to go to the right place.

or any other ways how to play Vimeo video dynamically on my android app?

**[I could have hardcoded the embedded code for video BUT I am giving dynamic content to my app as the video feeds changes every 1 hour - so parsing JSON is extremely necessary here].

Any idea how can I execute my plan?

Comment: Can you specify exactly what metadata you want to retrieve from the API and what you have already tried? Also, if you're building an Android app, have you tried using the official Android/Java library? https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java

Comment: I want to design an android app where users selects some categories(e.g-music,sports,science)- and then my app retrive videos from vimeo according to the user's category choice and show on my app and play@TommyPenner please help

Comment: Direct links to video files are only available to PRO and Business users: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Direct-links. Also, Vimeo doesn't support the iframe embed code in webviews or in-app browsers.

Have you tried the Android/Java library I linked previously to get a video's JSON response?

Answer (score 1):

Vimeo does not allow direct access to video links to standard user! You definitely GO PRO for that!

Now, To play the video you can use web view to embed the video!

Second, you can use this library to play video: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-deeplink-android

Last but not least, https://player.vimeo.com/video/97189640/config

I will not recommend this but a great hack for your problem!

Comment: why would I have to buy pro????I am just using the basic data api functionality which is free..I just want to show the vime video o my app

Comment: No. The Vimeo API is open to all Vimeo users, regardless of account type. Some features, however, are still limited depending on the account. For example, direct links to video files are only returned to PRO and Business members.

Comment: To show video in your app you need .mp4 link of that video which you will get from Json  and for that functionality is not available in basic

Comment: That part is correct - direct links to the video files hosted on Vimeo are only available to PRO/Business members. You should update your answer and specify this accordingly.

Comment: I have an issue with the js player api: the way it follows the privacy settings of a video is not nice (it doesn't really follow authentication).